# How to comunicate between client and server using TCP? send commands/receive data?

Tags: c#, client-server

How can I send commands to the client over the tcp from the server . 
How can I receive some information about the client's host when he's connected to server?
For example : Open apache,cmd etc..

Atm the only code I have made is for connecting to the server but I'm not sure how to send some data to the client for executing it.

Could someone help me with this?a tutorial or explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about doing is going to require some sort of server/client setup.  You will need to write an application that will listen on the TCP ports and take in the commands that are being sent.  It is best to use a specific port and just listen to that port for incoming commands.

My question is this though, why do you need to open a cmd on a remote machine?  I think most operating systems will disallow this and there does not seem to be much use for this above causing havoc.